# How to intersect a nested type in another type's definition

Tags: typescript, inheritance

I have two types,

```
type Foo = {
  [key: string]: {
    a: number
  }
}

type Bar = {
  b: number
}
```

and I want to create a third type that looks like:

```
type FooBar = {
  [key: string]: {
    a: number,
    b: number
  }
}
```

How could I define `FooBar` using inheritance (to guarantee that `Foo` and `FooBar` always have the same index signature/key)?

I already know that I can accomplish this with

```
type FooBar = {
  [key: string]: Foo[string] & bar
}
```

however that requires me to define the `key` separately for both `Foo` and `FooBar`.

Comment: While true you have to define `key` again it's not like that part of the definition is likely to diverge. If `Foo` had discrete keys I would understand your concern and would suggest a mapped type.. but if it's just indexable by string why bother with a more complex solution ?

Comment: Because my actual use case is more complex.

Comment: So `Foo` does not just have an index signature ? It has specific keys ? COuld you post something closer to your actual code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your simple example that just has a string signature, I would not complicate things any further. If `Foo` has discrete keys and you want to add `Bar` o every member you can use a mapped type:

```
type Foo = {
  [key: string]: {
    a: number
  }
}

type Bar = {
  b: number
}

type FooBar = {
  [P in keyof Foo]: Foo[P] & Bar
}
```